# Removing multiple images of carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I have created a sample Rails app that uses Carrierwave to upload images. I am able to upload multiple images. But now when I wish to delete them, I just got busy with searching of solution. I read in the documentation that we can use `@user.remove_avatar!` to delete single image. But how to delete multiple images?

Comment: show your some code like model associations

Comment: @AniketShivamTiwari Thanks for considering my question. But i am not saving it in some different model. It is stored as json in one model. I followed [this](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#multiple-file-uploads) for multiple image upload.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't feel the most Rails way of doing things but I have this method (which I modified from suggested code elsewhere).

```
def delete_picture
  @i = params[:i].to_i

  remain_images = @project.avatars # copy initial avatars
  delete_image = remain_images.delete_at(@i) # delete the target image
  delete_image.try(:remove!) # delete image
  @project.avatars = remain_images # re-assign back
  @project.save  
end
```

In my view where I output the images I have (where i is the image position):

```
 <%= link_to delete_picture_project_path(i: i), method: :delete, confirm: 'Delete?',       dataType: 'script', 'data-message' => 'Are you sure?', 'data-severity' => 'danger', :remote => true do %>
          <%= image_tag('delete') %>
        <% end %>
```

And in routes

```
resources :projects do 
member do
    delete 'delete_picture', to: "projects#delete_picture"
    end
end
```

This removes a single image where you have multiple images.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the answer upstairs, but when the image is left with only one file, the above method is not effective. I solved the problem in the following way.(I did it under model.)

```
def delete_picture(index)
  remain_pictures = self.pictures
  if remain_pictures.size != 1
    delete_picture = remain_pictures.delete_at(index)
    delete_picture.remove!
    self.pictures = remain_pictures
  else
    remove_reports!
  end
  save
end

@user.delete_picture(params[:index].to_i)
```

Comment: If you need to upload more than one file, I suggest you create a model that stores the file directly because it is more flexible.